# Get elapsed time in Javascript between two timestamps

Tags: javascript

I have a method which takes a while to execute and I want to calculate how much take the execution of method:

```
var start = Date.now();
execute();
var final = Date.now();

var diff = final - start;

var seconds = diff / 1000;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;

while(seconds >= 60)
{
   minutes++;
   seconds = Math.round(seconds/60);
}

while(minutes >= 60) {
   hours++;
   minutes = Math.round(minutes/60);
}
```

But I don't get correct information for minutes and seconds. Where is my mistake ?

The method takes somewhere 1 minute and few seconds, but in log shows only 20-40 seconds..

Comment: Your `diff` should be in milliseconds, not seconds!? so try `var seconds = diff / 1000;`

Comment: Even that, does not show correct info.

Comment: use `Date.getTime()` , not `now()`

Comment: Well I don't know but your loop is pretty unnecessary, why don't you use `var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);`? Then fo from there and if it's more then 1 hour do `var hours = parseInt(minutes / 60);` and subtract the hours from the left over seconds to get the rest...

Comment: Your calculations at the end are wrong, and an odd way of doing what you're trying to do as well.  Use `minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); seconds = seconds % 60;`

Comment: if you increase the `minutes` counter by `1`, `seconds` should by decreased by `60`, not divided by...

Comment: You can use stopwatch like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pvk6p/)

Answer (score 2):

```
startTime = Date.now();
execute();
endTime = Date.now();
totalSeconds = (endTime -startTime)/1000

hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds/3600)
minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds%3600)/60)
seconds = Math.floor((totalSeconds%3600)%60)

console.log(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, instead of dividing seconds by 60, you should subtract it. If your total time was 300 secs, in first loop, you will have seconds updated to 5 while minutes will be updated to 1.